# Where in blender menu is the option Cap Fill Type ? Can't find it

Tags: blender

I'm trying to do this tutorial.

[Hollow Cylinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIOpgKswi58)

But in my blender i can't find the Cap Fill Type.
I'm using blender 2.78

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the Operator Properties panel, it can be found at the bottom of the tool shelf <kbd>T</kbd>, note if the area is too small that you may have to scroll or expand the area to find the fill type. If the operator properties are not shown then there will be a small + that will bring it back.

[image: tool shelf]

You can also bring up the properties in a floating panel by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image: floating opertaort properties]

Comment: I tried but it's not there. When i first make Add > Mesh > Cylinder i see on the left it's in Add Cylinder mode or something and there there is the Cap Fill Type but that's only right after adding new Cylinder. After that when i'm going to other properties and menus and stuff i can't back to this Add Cylinder on the left that have the Cap Fill Type.  Even in you answer in the clip you see for a second the Add Cylinder.  I can't get back to it.

Comment: Now i clicked for example on the right on Modifiers then clicked on Add Modifier and selected Solidify. Now on the left before it was Add Cylinder where the Cap Fill Type was too. Now it's changed to Add Modifier. i need somehow to change it back to Add Cylinder and there is the Cap Fill Type.

Comment: Ah i read now here and i see you can't get back to this place to the Cap Fill Type if i understood it: https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-213436.html

Comment: @DanielHalfoni that link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cap fill type only after the immediate creation of the object. Even a slight change done to the object will vanish the option to set cap fill type.